# Странная работа цикла for

Tags: c#, for

Работая с циклами, заметил, что for введёт себя странно, если в нём будет Console.ReadLine (). А именно:

```cs
        for (int i = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); i < 5; i++)
```

Отработает нормально, то есть если я укажу 0, то и сработает он 5 раз.

```cs
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); i++)
```

Во втором случае он отработает всего раз, какое бы число больше 0 я не ввёл. Почему так происходит?

Update:

```cs
using System;

class VideoSharp {
    static void Main () {
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); i++)
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello!");
        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

Не отрабатывает как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализация `for (int i = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); ...` выполняется один раз - перед началом цикла.

Проверка условия продолжения цикла `for (...; i < Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); ...` выполняется перед каждой итерацией.

```
    int count = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello!");
    Console.ReadLine ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что каждый вызов ReadLine считывает новое число. А ты его, вероятно, не вводишь.

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу. Попробуйте сами, он отрабатывает неправильно.

Comment: Попробуй ввести 5 не 1 раз, а 5.

Comment: Всё работает как я ответил: https://ideone.com/7UdpzX

Comment: Проверил и вправду так. А почему, если я присваиваю введённое число i, то там нужно ввести всего 1 раз?